# Dynamic vlookup vba code did not populate figures

Tags: vba, dynamic, vlookup

Please help to advise where did it went wrong. Would like to create a vba vlookup for a different workbook

```
Sub Executelookup1()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range


Workbooks.Open ("V:\Finance\Systems-Risk-ERM\OrderToCash\C2C\Corp Credit Control\3. Monthly Combined Aging\2022\Apr22\Top Segments & Top All _Apr22.xlsx")

Set ws = Sheet3
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
ThisWorkbook.Activate

Set rng = ws.Range("K2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To rng
'On Error Resume Next

Range("K" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("F" & i).Value, wb.Sheets("TopSegments").Range("F:J"), 5, 0)

Next i

End Sub
```

I would like to have the end product to look like the picture displayed below.
[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` first to see what line is actually failing.

Comment: `Range("F" & i).Value` - `i` is an undeclared variable and has not been assigned a value and `Range` is implicitly `ActiveSheet.Range`, which may not be the sheet you want.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, i tried declaring i as an variable but i kept getting error type mismatch. i have amended the vba code in the original post.

Comment: `For i = 2 To rng` - `rng` is not a valid end. Try `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row`, `For i = 2 to lastRow`.

Comment: i tried it but the vlookup did not execute.

Comment: @BigBen, thanks for the assist! Managed to get the code running